# Converting text box to decimal

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm struggling to convert my text box "textBoxAmount into a decimal. I could use some help on where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

```
decimal dec_textBoxAmount;
dec_textBoxAmount = (decimal)int_textBoxValue / 100;
dec_textBoxAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxAmount.Text);
```

Comment: What is the middle line meant to achieve?

Comment: What's going wrong? Its not apparent from what's provided.

Comment: The middle line is there because the number that appears in the textBoxAmount needs to be 100 times less than the the number in the textBoxValue. With this code the numbers appearing in the textBoxAmount are integers at the moment.

Comment: so your actual decimal conversion is working - it's because your dividing through by the 100 which is an integer and therefore makes everything an integer. You need dec_textBoxAmount = (decimal)int_textBoxValue / Convert.ToDecimal(100); to make everything into decimals

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
Decimal value = -1;
if (decimal.TryParse(textBoxAmount.Text, out value))
{
//Do something with your value
}else
{
//something went wrong with the conversion - i.e. not in a recognisable format so
//display some kind of error message
}
```

However, there's various spin controls that return decimal types and allow you to set min/max ranges and they reject any bad text etc.

Cheers
Simon

Comment: to be fair - that is really really picky

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Decimal.TryParse(textBoxAmount.Text, out returnValue)
{
   //success

}
else
{
   //failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`decimal.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) thus:

```
string txtBoxValue = textBoxAmount.Text ;
decimal amount ;
bool parsedOk = decimal.TryParse( txtBoxValue , out amount ) ;
```

At the end of this, `parsedOk` will be `true` if the conversion succeeded and `amount` will have the value. If the parse failed, `parsedOk` will be `false` and `amount` will be set to `default(decimal)` (e.g., `0m`).

Answer (score 0):

```
 decimal dec_textBoxAmount;
 dec_textBoxAmount = (decimal)int_textBoxValue / 100;

 if (Decimal.TryParse(textBoxAmount.Text, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dec_textBoxAmount))
 {
      //Conversion is successfull
  }
```